# problemas 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin main.js attach SourceMap

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-cli

Hola alguien podría explicarme a que se debe que cuando tiro un npm run start sobre un proyecto de angular me tira 93% after chunk asset optimization SourceMapDevToolPlugin main.js attach SourceMap y como puedo solucionarlo. gracias!

Comment: Por favor repasar [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y le faltan detalles, motivos por los que puede terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: ok! consulto porque soy medio nuevo con el tema de angular y últimamente cuando corro un proyecto me tira ese error que antes no sucedia.

Comment: busque de hacerlo correr con el siguiente comando ng serve --sourceMap=false corre bien pero me gustaria saber que debo configurar para poder correrlo normalmente.